# AAVE deletion of alveolar stops before the ending -ing

Tags: phonology, african-american-vernacular-english

[They riding for us](https://youtu.be/C_UHymtsOdE?t=128)  **/ˈɹaɪjɪn/**

I'd like to know whether whether it's represented somehow in writing.

Secondly, what phonological process enable it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [-ing vs -in' ending](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59653/ing-vs-in-ending)

Comment: The question is about the deletion of "d" in "riding", not about the final nasal.

Comment: Oops you can ignore that comment then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ["Phonological and Phonetic Characteristics of African American Vernacular English":](https://repository.lib.ncsu.edu/bitstream/handle/1840.2/2062/Thomasj.1749-818X.2007.00029.pdf?sequence=1)

> A fairly common feature of AAE is devoicing, often accompanied by glottalization, of morpheme-final /d/ , /g/, and /b/ , as in mud produced as [mʌʔt] or [mʌʔ]. Outright deletion of morpheme final voiced stops is possible, too, for example, [mʌː] and the deletion can extend to voiceless stops, for example, [ɹæ] rack.

The "d" in "riding" is morpheme-final, so this rule certainly applies. To me, it sounds like he's glottalizing it, creating something like [ˈraɪʔ.ɪn].